# TinyMCE, removing and shuffling the objects

Tags: tinymce

I am adding textareas and removing textareas (with tinymces assigned to them) by removing the very dom elements creating them.

What I had not appreciated was that there is some tiny mce object with the original mapping code to textareas and regardless of if you remove the element, the object still exists and ends up posting incorrect data through post data.

My question is in 2 parts:

1. How are you suppose to properly remove a tinymce editor?
2. I re-shuffle textarea names and ids so that I always have post data starting from 0 and going up... How in this case, do I re-shuffle the tinymce objects so that they are addressing the correct tinymce object?

I have looked for about 3 hours now and managed to remove tinyMCE.editors... but then I need to re-shuffle the references the other editors have.

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct behaviour to remove an editor is:

   tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, your_editor_id);
2. For your use case i suggest you remove an editor instance first before you reinit a new editor instance. Shuffling in the background can yield unwanted results.

Comment: so, instead of re-shuffling. Just delete all iterations of the tinymce, and re-make them?

Comment: did you insert your editor id (example: replace your_editor_id with 'your_real_editor_id')?

Comment: "so, instead of re-shuffling. Just delete all iterations of the tinymce, and re-make them? " - yes, even thought re-shufling could work - this way you save you some possible trouble

Comment: I did ofcourse replace the id there :D... I even started with a fresh page.